# When reading in data from a csv file in C#, how to skip data in Trailer line?

Tags: c#, csv

I'm reading in data from a .csv file to Visual Studio, and I want the program to skip the Trailer line (as it contains different data from the rest of the file, and throws an "Input was not in correct format exception").

I was able to skip the Header line using this code in front of my while loop:

```
//Skip first line in file
string headerLine = sr.ReadLine();
```

But obviously I can't use the same technique with my Trailer line as that requires I run through the loop. How can I accomplish this?

Edit: Here is the data from the csv file (Header and Trailer Lines begin w/ H & T respectively, and all other lines begin w/ "action codes" A, C, or D):

H   UpdateFile  4/1/2017

C   10006   4846482 106 Lyle Landley    432 Ferrari Spider  1000    5   30000   2/4/2017    2/28/2017

A   10010   2323232 110 Jerry Seinfeld  555 Porsche 911 Targa   345 5   10532   3/1/2017    3/8/2017

D   10012   4689292 112 Michael Dukakis 865 AM General  Humvee  150 4   20000   3/3/2017    3/5/2017

A   10013   6661313 113 Jason Vorhees   123 Jeep    Wrangler    500 3   605 3/4/2017    3/10/2017

C   10018   6482648 117 Stephen Curry   555 Mercedes    AMG 321 5   4566    3/14/2017   3/17/2017

D   10019   1111111 104 Robert Knight   865 Ford    Boss 302    764 5   12004   3/15/2017   3/21/2017

C   10020   1112222 118 Allen Iverson   669 Tesla   Model S 3333    4   3533    4/1/2017    4/9/2017

T   UpdateFile  4/1/2017    7   31

Also, Here is the method that the above snippet comes from:

```
public static void ReadUpdateFile(ref Car[] updates, ref int updateCount)
    {
        string path = "UpdateFile.csv";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        //Figure this out
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        //Skip first line in file
        string headerLine = sr.ReadLine();

        //How to skip last line in file?

        while (sr.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] updateArray = line.Split(',');

            DateTime rentInDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/9999");
            DateTime rentOutDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001");
            bool isValid = DateTime.TryParse(updateArray[12], out rentInDate);
            bool isValidToo = DateTime.TryParse(updateArray[11], out rentOutDate);
            //I'm using these new/temporary DateTime variables to read in the DateTime data from the excel sheet, for some reason VS had a problem doing this
            //It threw an exception relating to the data not being in the correct format

            if (isValid)
            {
                updates[updateCount] = new Car(char.Parse(updateArray[0]), int.Parse(updateArray[1]), 
                    updateArray[2], new Customer(int.Parse(updateArray[3]), updateArray[4]), int.Parse(updateArray[5]), 
                    updateArray[6], updateArray[7], int.Parse(updateArray[8]), int.Parse(updateArray[9]), 
                    decimal.Parse(updateArray[10]), rentOutDate, rentInDate);
                WriteLine(updates);
                ReadKey();
            }

            else
            {
                rentInDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                updates[updateCount] = new Car(char.Parse(updateArray[0]), int.Parse(updateArray[1]),
                    updateArray[2], new Customer(int.Parse(updateArray[3]), updateArray[4]), int.Parse(updateArray[5]),
                    updateArray[6], updateArray[7], int.Parse(updateArray[8]), int.Parse(updateArray[9]),
                    decimal.Parse(updateArray[10]), rentOutDate, rentInDate);
            }
            updateCount++;
        }
    }
```

To clarify, I stored the csv data in an array under a Car class that I created.
Thanks!

Comment: can you show what the CSV content looks like also show the code where you are splitting the file into a string[].. please do not post partial code and expect others to know and or guess what it is you have coded on your side. if you set up your code properly and read all of the data into a string[] or a class representing the CSV file datastructure.. you can easily loop thru the lines checking if the line contains Trailer line, if so call the `continue`; method but I am only guessing since I forgot to wear my `ESP Hat` today

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks for the input! Hope this helps

Comment: static methods and ref parameters; clearly a c programmer originally then! :)

Comment: this for starters does not look like a `CSV` file also you do not need to use the `Peek()` method, if this is truly `.CSV` file and you have left out the `,` by accident, then you could ReadAllLines into a List, and from there Split the lines into an String[] array or like I said earlier create a class that mimics the structure of your file including the header and use substring methods or `.Contains` method to check for `if string / Contains` `T UpdateFile` if so either skip or exit or write do whatever you need to do..

Answer (score 0):

Read it anyway, and then either:

1. put the line of code that does the parsing wrapped up in a try/catch, then either handle the failure appropriately (log it to a status window for the user to see, or suppress it if you're sure it's irrelevant) or-
2. pre-empt the problem; perhaps the last line is a single blank line denoting end of file- use a code like `if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line))` to detect the line and move on to other things

Which you'll choose depends on how often you expect garbage to be elsewhere in the file. If the file is machine prepared, maybe just 2 is appropriate. If the data comes from a human, perhaps do both

Edit: now we can see the last line begins with a T, you can employ advice 2 like this:

```
if(line.StartsWith("T")) 
  break;
```

You have to do this in the loop, immediately after the line has been read. You can't "skip the trailer" outside of the loop because you haven't got to it at that point. You only reach the last line by running the loop several times

Comment: not sure how this answers the OP's question in regards to parsing looping checking and reading lines then continuing

Comment: He hasn't really given us a lot to go on but I believe the posted advice is adequate for exception handling in general file reading; you either wrap your processing code in a try and let it fail if the input is malformed, or you aim to detect malformed input before it's processed. A third option exists, to read and process it into a default state, then throw it away later, but that seems more trouble than it's worth for a final line that is not to be preserved

Comment: I agree not enough information not to mention the OP is not posting the code that throws the format exception error.. we can guess until the OP tells us otherwise LOL

Comment: @CaiusJard This makes sense, thank you! I am new to this, appreciate you being cool about the help. To clarify, the exception is thrown for the entire argument inside the Car class in the else statement. What can I add that would help in figuring this out?

Comment: You can run the code in a debugger (press play in visual studio) and when the code throws the exception the debugger will pause the app, and you can investigate the values of the array elements and determine why they're not to specification

Comment: Ps you don't need to parse a char. A string can be treated as an array of characters. myString[1] will return the second char of the myString string. myStringArray[4][2] will return the char at position 3 of the fifth string in the array of strings

Comment: As an "other pair of eyes" feedback , your code is just an absolute mash of unreadable stuff. unreadable not in that I can't interpret the letters, I mean it in the sense that I can't easily read what it's doing from how it's presented. Consider using File.ReadAllLines to read the file, consider, after splitting each line, putting each element into its own named variable first rather than creating a Car and passing 20 parsed arguments to the constructor. Consider improving your car class so it has methods that parse string inputs, so you can call `myNewCar.ParseRentStartDate(splitCsv[7])`

Comment: Or give Car named properties with sensible defaults that remain if the parsing doesn't work out, then you can dump the isValid,isValidToo blah blah.  Changes like these make code self documenting and easier to maintain and debug. The more you do on a single line (20 constructor arguments) the less easy it is to find which one causes a problem